# JavaScript: Cannot properly return array from function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a small problem with **javascript** that could be illustrated by following example:

```
function inlineSplit ( string, delimeter )
{
    delimiter = typeof delimeter !== 'undefined' ? delimeter : ",";
    return new Array( string.split(delimiter) );
}
```

I would assume, that after performing following operation the `test` variable would be an array:

```
var test = inlineSplit( "a,b,c" );
```

To my surprise, function returns a single string. In a following test:

```
alert( test[0] ); // results in "a,b,c"
alert( test[1] ); // results in ""
```

What may be wrong? It's been a long time since I coded in javascript, and right now I'm beginning to feel kind of dumb not understanding what's exactly wrong... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.split()` function returns an array; there's no need to build one. Your code builds a new array that will have one entry, the array returned by `.split()`.

An easier way to build an array is to use an array literal:

```
return [1, 2, 3];
```

Whatever you pass in to the `alert()` function will be coerced to a string, so it's not the best way to analyze behavior.

Comment: Yup, that's the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you are putting an array in an another array that's because `alert( test[0] );` returning you the first array that you made by spliting your string.

use

```
 return string.split(delimiter);
```

instead of

```
return new Array( string.split(delimiter) );
```